# Is my cat pooping on my bed to get attention? How do I get it to stop?

Tags: cats, behavior, toilet-training, defecation

Ok I think my cat is taunting me....

He has a very annoying habit of doing poops on my bed and I can't figure out why.

Initially it was when he was new and related to any changes in the home or us being away which I guess must have been stressful.

We changed his litter - he pooped on the bed. 
Each time we got back from holiday he pooped on the bed. 
He pooped under the dinning table whilst we were away (my brother was house sitting). 
We bought a new and rather overpriced sofa (it was our first piece of new furniture as a couple.) I got home from work the day it arrived to find a poop on the velvet cover. I cleaned it up and it happened twice after that. Eventually he stopped pooping on it and touch wood no accidents since then.

He's fine when we travel now but for some reason on the odd occasion he still likes to poop on the bed.

Now, he does warn us which is the bit I can't work out. So before he poops he basically meows very loudly from the bed room - if we don't go and see him he'll take a Poop on the bed!! How mean is that!?

We give him tones of attention and with lots of love and strokes. He has toys that we rotate to keep him entertained and his litter tray is very well maintained, an ipad of cat games (it's fine to judge me most my friends do). He has a fully organic diet and get's garden time twice a day. We've also got another cat and they get on very well.

I've put this pooping down to attention seeking but I just don't know how to stop it. I already give him lots of love and attention. If anyone has any clues to stop this irritating behavior please let me know.

Comment: Please tell us how old your cat is, how old your other cat is, and how many litter boxes you have.  Please tell us how large the litter box is.  Also, please tell us if he deficates outside in the garden when you taken him outside.

Comment: Sara I'm curious to know if you have found a way to get your cat to stop.. because I too have a problem where my cat poops on my guest bed..He to is very well cared for played with and given the best food. I personally think excuse my language but he's just a little attention who're and when I can't give him the hours he needs he acts out and does it or when I travel as well. I have thrown away so many sheets but he continues I've tried punishing him once and he literally pooped shortly after as ifvto say FU.. I'm at my wits end. He's only a year old this can't continue.

Answer (score 8):

Of course first, you need to take him to the vet to rule out medical issues.  The loud meow before defecating could be pain.  After you know there is no medical issues, here are some things you could try:

**LARGER/MORE LITTER BOXES:**  Since you have 2 cats, you will need 2 or 3 litter boxes.  You want to make his litter box experience enjoyable.  Typically, litter boxes you purchase at the pet stores are not large enough. Personally, I use two large storage containers for my two cat.  They have high sides and are large enough for the cats to turn around comfortably.  I also have a stepstool leading up to the box so they can easily get in and out. Also, some cats like to urinate in one box and defecate in another (I have one of those kitties). Your cat may simply want another box.

**LITTER BOX BULLYING:**  This occurs when one cat waits near the box (around a corner, perhaps) for the other cat to finish using the litter box.  When he finishes and gets out of the box, the waiting cat ambushes him.  This may look like play, but it can be a form of dominance.  Make sure your other kitty is not lying in wait when your cat uses the litter box.  If you do have this situation, you will need to find places, with more than one exit point, to put extra boxes.

**LITTER:**  If your cat will defecate in the garden, you may need to mix your litter with dirt from outside to entice him to use it.

**ENTERTAINMENT:**  First of all, I am impressed with the level of entertainment you give your kitties.  My cats like iPad cat games, too!  (Be careful about taking them outside, there are a lot of dangers for cats outside, even if supervised.). How much vertical space do you have for the kitties.   Maybe placing a tall cat tree, with different levels, next to your bed will distract your cat because he will find the tree more fun than your bed.

A few things to note:  (1) You probably need to get rid of any bed sheets or comforter that he's used.  Sometimes, washing is not enough.  Cats have a superior sense of smell. (2) I understand you want nice furniture, but it isn't very practical with pets.  Even without your particular problem, you will always have cat hair, a few scratches, and don't forget the puke stains.  However, the relationship and love of a cat far outweighs these.  (3) I know it is difficult to understand, but your  cat is not trying to be mean or vindictive.  These are human characteristics, not cat's.  Your cat is trying to tell you something.   Sometimes, it can be difficult figuring it out, but thank you for seeking answers here.

I wish you and your kitty the best!

Comment: Excellent answer, especially the points about the cat not doing it to be mean and about the vet trip -- breaking litter box protocol is often an indication that the cat is ill.  Washing in cold water with one of the scent-binding enzyme preparations may be enough to remove the subliminal suggestion that this is a good place, but changing out the bedclothes is more certain. (Counter-scents are good enough for humans, but _not_ for cats.)

Answer (score 3):

I am having the same problem with my one-year-old maine coon male. It stopped for a while, but anything can set it off and breaking the cycle is difficult.

Try Cat Attract cat litter. You can mix it with your existing litter to stretch it.

Feliway difusers. These really help.

Have you changed your cat's diet lately? If so, go back to what you had before.

And try rescue remedy drops.

Know your cat. Does your cat like high places or tuck away underneath things. Make sure they have a place to go to feel safe. (Yes, I know your place is safe, but cats aren't necessarily the most rational.)

I think my cat got stressed by a lot of things. The pet store stopped carrying the dry food I've been feeding, so there was a change. My house guests left and so he lost some buddies that he bonded with. I'm moving furniture around the house -- just bought a condo and am trying to figure out where things go -- and that's a huge change.

Poor baby. It sucks, but it's his only way of telling me he's upset.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add one more detail to what KittyConsultant has already said.

Try to use sand in litter box. if you have this issue from the very begining, I can think your cat it's very happy of his litter box. Cats are obsessed with "digging" and filling up the results of defecation. And sand is more natural for them than anything else. Try a big and deep litter box full of sand.